# Prevent form submission on 'return' press on Edge though not on Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 'details' tag in html that opens and closes when a user presses enter. On edge, when the user presses enter on the 'details' tag the form submits. The task I am working on asks to prevent the submission when enter is pressed on the tag.

My current attempt at a solution is:

```
var returnKey = 13;
var openProperty = 'open';

$('details').keypress(function(event){
    if ( event.which == returnKey ) {
      event.preventDefault();

      if ( $(this).hasOwnProperty(openProperty) ) {
        $(this).removeProp("open");
      } else {
        $(this).prop("open", true);
      }
    }
});
```

This fixes the problem in IE/Edge due to preventDefault, however in chrome and firefox the 'details' tag no longer opens and closes. This section was added to attempt to stop that:

```
   if ( $(this).hasOwnProperty(openProperty) ) {
    $(this).removeProp("open");
  } else {
    $(this).prop("open", true);
  }
```

This opens the tag but never allows for it to shut.

Comment: You will need to create a [MCVE] in order to demonstrate your broken code.  From what you have provided it is impossible to tell what you are doing or what the issue is. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) methode to toggle between the property's values :

```
if ( $(this).attr(openProperty) ) {
  $(this).removeAttr("open");
} else {
  $(this).attr("open", '');
}
```